# ListView multichoice implementation only one click more than one selection

Tags: android, listview, multiple-choice

I try to implement a listview multichoice. I achive display all my contact in a listview with checkBox item. My problem is that when check ONLY one item there is lots of element are being cheked. Could you please help?

```
public class SelectNewGroupChatMembers extends ListFragment implements
        LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnItemClickListener {
/** Defines a tag for identifying log entries */
private static final String TAG = "SelectNewGroupChatMembers";
/** The main query adapter */
private ContactsAdapter mAdapter;
/** ListView which will display contacts */
ListView mListView;
/** Fragments require an empty constructor. */
public SelectNewGroupChatMembers() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Create the main contacts adapter
    mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "clicked");
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);     
    // Initialize the loader, and create a loader identified by ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // If this is the loader for finding contacts in the Content Provider
    if (id==ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID) {
        Uri contentUri = ContactsQuery.CONTENT_URI;
        Log.i(TAG, contentUri.toString());
        // Create a new CursorLoader with the following query parameters.
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                contentUri,
                ContactsQuery.PROJECTION,
                ContactsQuery.SELECTION,
                null,
                ContactsQuery.SORT_ORDER);
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader - incorrect ID provided ( "+ id +" )");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    // This swaps the new cursor into the adapter.
    if (loader.getId() == ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID) {
        Log.i(TAG,cursor.toString());
        // The asynchronous load is complete and the data
        // is now available for use. Only now can we associate
        // the queried Cursor with the SimpleCursorAdapter.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    if (loader.getId() == ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID) {
        // When the loader is being reset, clear the cursor from the adapter.
        // This allows the cursor resources to be freed.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}

private class ContactsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ContactsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, null, 0);
        // Stores the inflater for the later use
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // Inflate the list item layout
        final View itemLayout = 
                mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_new_group_chat_members, viewGroup, false);
        // Use ViewHolder design pattern to store each view resource.
        // This allows bindView() to retrieve stored references instead of 
        // calling findViewById for each instance of the layout.
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.contactName = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        holder.contactNo = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.userInfo);
        // Store the resourceHolder instance in Layout.
        // This makes resourceHolder available to bindView
        // and other methods that receive a handle to the item view
        itemLayout.setTag(holder);
        return itemLayout;
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Get handles to individual view sources
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        final String contactName = cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.DISPLAY_NAME);
        final String contactNumber = cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.PHONE_NUMBER);
        holder.contactName.setText(contactName);
        holder.contactNo.setText(contactNumber);
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView contactName, contactNo;
    }
}

public interface ContactsQuery {
    // This query ID will be used in Loader
    final static int QUERY_ID = 1;
    // A content URI for the Contacts table
    final static Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    final static String SELECTION = null;
    final static String SORT_ORDER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME;
    final static String [] PROJECTION = {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        SORT_ORDER,
    };
    final static int ID = 0;
    final static int LOOKUP_KEY = 1;
    final static int DISPLAY_NAME = 2;
    final static int PHONE_NUMBER = 3;
    final static int SORT_KEY = 4;
}
}
```

My layout file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/userImage"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_user" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/userImage"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/userImage"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/userImage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userImage"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="ContactName"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userInfo"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/userImage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userImage"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="UserInfo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

At final my code is like above. This code queries contacts and display them on a listview which including a checkBox. I tried some different code snippets but with all my tries i get same result. My problem is that when check ONLY one item there is lots of element are being cheked. Could you help please?

Comment: Where is your code for the list view and its adapter?

Comment: There is no problem with listview load and adapter, I'm in trouble with one click lots of check

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are manipulating the checkbox on item click in this code. Ideally `onItemClick` you should get the Holder object out of the view tag by calling view.getTag. In your holder there is a checkbox view instance so you can enable the checkbox there. So something like this on your *onItemClick* method.

```
Holder holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
holder.checkbox.setChecked(!checkbox.isChecked());
```

Comment: I have no problem with setCheck, I'm in trouble with one click lots of check :)